# See sent request with rest client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rest-client

How can I see the complete HTTP request sent with REST client? I didn't find it in the doc...
https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client

What I want to see is something like:  "https://mysite.com?param1=sthg"

Answer (score 0):

Check rest client logging in [docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rest-client/1.6.1/frames#Logging)

To enable logging you can

set RestClient.log with a ruby Logger or set an environment variable to avoid modifying the code (in this case you can use a file name, “stdout” or “stderr”):

```
$ RESTCLIENT_LOG=stdout path/to/my/program
```